# UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

I'm using custom `UICollectionView` on my app. However, I have a problem that make my app crash. The log for the crash:
**Note: This bug doesn't occur on iOS 8**

```
2015-05-29 11:49:26.316 app9to5[1834:607] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0x7fca0e00> {length = 2, path
= 0 - 14}'

> First throw call stack: (  
       CoreFoundation                      0x039b61e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180  
       libobjc.A.dylib                     0x036808e5 objc_exception_throw + 44  
       CoreFoundation                      0x039b6048 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136  
       Foundation                          0x016954de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116  
       UIKit                               0x02be0866 __45-[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]_block_invoke + 1793  
       UIKit                               0x02bdfaed -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 1376  
       UIKit                               0x02ba5603 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 173  
       UIKit                               0x025c8964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355  
       libobjc.A.dylib
```

Please help me to resolve. Thank you so much!

Comment: can you give me some of your code, especially in your layout attributes setting function and your collectionview delegate?

Comment: @EugeneNguyen: You can check this code in the link https://gist.github.com/cuong-nguyen-ta/5b7f73f2fb9a316ffcf5
I think it occurred when i'm calling

 `[self.collectionView reloadData];`

Comment: @EugeneNguyen this is the function setting layout attributes
https://gist.github.com/cuong-nguyen-ta/22f6d7c5039d3743a4f1
Please help me to resolve. Thank so much!

Comment: One more information about this bug. I saw

015-05-29 19:57:18.772 app9to5[2464:607] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionViewData.m:357

in the log screen

Comment: You should check the layout constraint outlets. One of the constraint outlets can be nil.

Comment: @ridvankucuk I don't use a storyboard. I used the code for CollectionViewController. 
I debugged in my project and I saw the crash when I run over the function `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`
You can see the function on the link https://gist.github.com/cuong-nguyen-ta/22f6d7c5039d3743a4f1. 
Thanks for support me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

In `-(NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect`  you put this:

```
for(NSInteger i=0 ; i < self.collectionView.numberOfSections; i++) {
    for (NSInteger j=0 ; j < [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:i]; j++) {
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:j inSection:i];
        [attributes addObject:[self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    }
}
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: @Nghia you are returning all attributes, not just attributes intersecting the specified rect

Answer (score 3):

Try invalidating the layout before you call reloadData on collection View.

```
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: I tried with

 `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];`

However, it doesn't work. @@
Thanks for your comment.

Comment: works perfectly. A lot of answers where recommending that I create a new collectionviewlayout and to be honest this seemed over kill. This answer worked for me when using 2 collection views. thx

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do this

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```